# H-bridge: Low-side N-channel MOSFET burns occasionally

Tags: mosfet, pwm, h-bridge, overheat

I am just getting into electronics and my first project is a 555 timer PWM (0-100) and an H-bridge to drive a motor for my brewing equipment (500 mA max. rating).

Here is the setup:

[image]

I have a 12 V circuit, a mechanical switch to set the direction (powers up either "left side" or "right side" MOSFETs of the H-bridge). As I was afraid of shoot-through
I added an extra P-channel MOSFET that is driven by the PWM and supplies the load.

The problem: Occasionally one of the MOSFETs (low-side) just burns after a while (gets hot/ smells and drain and source are shorted now), the motor stops and only has short flickers of movement.

Observations:
I have the feeling that the pot position is connected to the problem. I think that it happens when the motor is insufficiently supplied with voltage and stops moving. If I stay in the 50% range or full load range, I have the feeling it works well, but still only a feeling.

I experienced that this happens much faster if the pot is 100 kΩ and not 10 kΩ, but I have no clue why.

Now that one of the MOSFETs has burned, I tried checking if the PWM is flawed and surprisingly it only does not work if the switch is supplying the side of the broken MOSFET (I disconnected the out pin from the circuit for checking that). The other way round the PWM is fine.

Can you tell me where I messed up?

Comment: Sounds like it is related to low duty cycles and induction pulses of the motor, but I need to think a bit about your free wheeling diodes. What make/type of motor is that actually?

Comment: It is a Grothen G928 motor: see here [link](https://www.amazon.de/Fafeicy-Peristaltikpumpe-Hochwertige-Dosierpumpe-Aquarienlabor/dp/B08FT4BY5K/ref=asc_df_B08FT4BY5K/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=474032841989&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12709030452802841324&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9062725&hvtargid=pla-972218601585&psc=1&th=1&psc=1)

Comment: And please note NPN and PNP has nothing to do with MOSFets, please, those have N- or P-channels ;-)

Comment: Noted and corrected, Thanks :)

Comment: Nicely written question. Can you clarify "burns" is the MOSFET getting hot before it fails?

Comment: Can you try an experiment for me. Reduce R3 and R4 to 1k and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: thanks! yes it gets hot and it smells. I will try. i just had the fear that maybe the h bridge lowside could interfere with the gates? But I dont know if that ever could happen, it being connected to ground.

Comment: (Currently, a double-pole switch would functionally replace the H-bridge.) Do you actuate Switch1 while the motor is running?

Comment: Both your P channel and N channel FETs have gate threshold voltages of one or two volts. This means that when you throw Switch1 iopen, the gate capacitance of the two FETs must be discharged by R4 (50K), and both FETs (X15 and X17) will be on as this gate voltage drops between 10 volts and 2 volts.  Royc suggestion might help to speed up the switching time, but it is better to put in some dead time.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is an on-off-on switch. So there would be some dead time in between (i just did not have a model for the proper switch so i used this one. Sorry.) Wouldnt the gate voltage would be in equilibrium within split seconds? The problem occurs after some time and only occasionally, but is reproducible. Thats what confuses me. But i will try the smaller resistors asap! Thanks for all the input! And also for the corrections on the title ;)!

Comment: (`Wouldn't the gate voltage would be in equilibrium within split seconds?` that would be a problem, as there would be a shoot-through left *and* right.)

Comment: You  misunderstand when I say dead time; when the switch is in the position shown on the schematic and you turn it "off," the voltage on X18-gate will start to drop as its gate capacitance is discharged through R3.  It will start at 12 volts, and when it reaches 10 volts, it will start to turn X18 "on."  But with ten volts also on x16-gate, x16 is also "on," causing shoot-through.  Both will stay on until the voltage on the two gates drops to one or two volts.  Simulate it and you can see.

Comment: Like John and greybeard mention you need proper sequencing of the gate voltage/charge/discharge, a break-before-make scheme between upper/lower part of each half-bridge, and also both the half-brigdes.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I am currently testing several possibilities. I copied the circuit to a breadboard (again) and tried 50k and 2k resistors at R3/R4 of the MOSFETS. and it worked both ?! I also rewired the whole thing: The switch now turns on/off the PWM cycle/ AND the H-bridge (either MOSFET-right or MOSFET left) at the same time (I will update the schematic asap). A cheap shoot-through workaraound i guess? The circuit is working at the breadboard!!! BUT it does not work when soldered to a board (tried twice already). X16 and D39 broke down and are shorted. I'll double check again.

Comment: Do you think the bread board can have that kind of influence on the circuit that a soldered part has not? I will try to implement a dead time for the Mosfets!

Comment: Hey there, After some welding and testing (replaced one of the N-channel Mosfets with a LED (Connection of Gate-Source of original mosfet wiring) i found out that the gate of the mosfet on the "off" side of the bridge gets a pwm signal which is not measurable by my multimeter. So it seems that it is always slightly open and thats why the MOSFET on the opposite side always burns out. The led brightness is connected to the speed/ poti position and has following pattern: low motor speed --> OFF-ON-OFF <-- high motor speed. I still have no clue why but i am getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it.
It seems that the MOSFET gates on the low side were powered via the negative pole and therefore the N-channel MOSFET on the "off" side was slightly ON which lead to fast burn out of the MOSFET.
Found out via an LED that I placed instead of the MOSFET between Gate --> Source of the N-channel MOSFETs.
Although the breadboard worked and the through hole soldered version did not, I found out that the LED also responded on the breadboard. But much much less bright. So it seems that both circuits were faulty but the breadboard circuit had too much resistance for the gate to turn the MOSFET even slightly ON. I checked all the resistances and found that the connections on the breadboard had much more resistance (I had to wire 2 breadboards together because one was too small). Sometimes the difference was even 10 to 100 Ω!
Here is the new circuit. (The pulldown resistors did not change much/anything. The MOSFETS burned at 50k and at 1.5k)
And the circuit has a different, namely a "ON-OFF-ON" switch. Therefore there is a small pause between forward and reverse. I don't know if shootthrough would occur with the depicted switch but I did not have a proper model for the switch.
All the best
Andi
[image]

Comment: The correct terms for the state of a MOSFET (or BJT) is ON and OFF. "Open" implies an OFF state, but from context it seems you mean ON. In your new schematic, the diodes D43 and D44 will limit the low gate drive to about 0.7V and may be above threshold. It would be better to put a diode from the common sources of X15 and X16 to GND. You probably have other problems as well, due to use of proto-boards. And you really need to get a scope to troubleshoot properly - even a cheap $30 unit would be OK.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I corrected it. What kind of troubleshoot unit do you have in mind? I don't understand your approach of replacing D44/D43 with a diode from the source of X15/X16 to GND. The voltage that powered the gate of X15/X16 originated from the ground side as far as I could tell. I disconnected the switch from the MOSFET in question and checked it. So the problem would persist if I allow current from the GND side to the MOSFET gates?!

Comment: You really need to check the gate voltages, which need to be solid. And you need to consider that you are only driving the load high during the PWM ON. If you will be driving a motor, this will be problematic, I suggest that you use a conventional bridge circuit. By deciding on this weird design, you "own" it and need to troubleshoot accordingly. IMHO this design is fatally flawed, and I can't help.